# How to set the path of the socketio server to the path of the user?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

So my question is how do you se the path of the user to the path where the socket broadcasts to. Right now I have 2 sockets, one default to broadcast to all channel and to work on all channels and one just to broadcast to a specific channel. Even when I add `window.location.pathname` or `location.pathname` it doesn't broadcast to any channel at all. So what can I do to fix it?

My JS Code-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

  var sockit = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/' + window.location.pathname);

  var e = document.querySelector("#broadcast");

  try {
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  } catch(error) {
    TypeError
  }

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = () => {
      if (result == "channel") {
        var message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
        socket.emit('submit post', {'message': message});
        document.querySelector("#message").value = '';
        return false;
      } else if (result == "worldwide") {
        var message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
        socket.emit('submit worldwide post', {'message': message});
        document.querySelector("#message").value = '';
        return false;
      } else {
        var message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
        socket.emit('submit post', {'message': message});
        document.querySelector("#message").value = '';
        return false;
      };
    };
  });

  sockit.on('announce post', data => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `<strong> ${data.username} </strong> : ${data.message} <small class="float-right"> ${data.time} </small>`;
    document.querySelector('#posts').append(li);
  });

  socket.on('announce post worldwide', data => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `<strong> admin </strong> : ${data.message} <small class="float-right"> Broadcasted Worldwide at ${data.time} </small>`;
    document.querySelector('#posts').append(li);
  });
});
```

My Flask Server Code (if that is necessary)-

```
@socketio.on("submit post")
def post(data):

    current_channel = session.get("current_channel")

    if len(messages_created[current_channel]) > 100:
        messages_created[current_channel].pop(0)

    messages_created[current_channel].append([session.get("username"), data["message"], datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")])

    message = data["message"]

    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

    emit("announce post", {"message": message, "time": time, "username": session.get("username")}, current_channel=current_channel, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on("submit worldwide post")
def worldwide(data):

    messages_created2.update({data["message"] : datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")})

    message = data["message"]

    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

    emit("announce post worldwide", {"message": message, "time": time}, current_channel=current_channel, broadcast=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit title if it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add the rooms feature mentioned in the socketio documentation and it would only broadcast to the one specific channel